# Button not navigated. shows error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have assumed a name `gobut` for my button. But, while run the app, it says error. I didn't give same name for the buttons. But, i dunno y it shows error. I have added all my code for your reference. Answer me please.

ERROR:

> Error 1   The type 'MyApp.goto1' already contains a definition for
>   'gobut'   C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Release\goto1.g.cs  47  49  MyApp

XAML CODE:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox Name="txtbx" InputScope="Number" MaxLength="3"/>
            <Button Content="Go!" Name="gobut"/>
        </Grid>
```

C# CODE:

```
public partial class goto1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public goto1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void gobut(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int num = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(txtbx.Text, out num) && num > 0 && num < 115)
            {
                string site;
                site = num.ToString();
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page" + site + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Value between 1 to 114");
            }
        } 
    }
```

goto1.g.cs code:

```
internal System.Windows.Controls.Button gobut;
/.../
this.gobut = ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(this.FindName("gobut")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this

XAML Code

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">                
            <TextBox Name="txtbx" InputScope="Number" MaxLength="3"></TextBox>
            <Button Content="Go!" Name="gobut" Click="gobut_Click"></Button>                
        </Grid>
```

C# code

```
private void gobut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int num = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(txtbx.Text, out num) && num > 0 && num < 115)
            {
                string site;
                site = num.ToString();
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page" + site + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Value between 1 to 114");
            }
        }
```

i got the output

Answer (score 0):

You button name and method name is same. Change either one of them.

Comment: button name ok. but where should i change method name

Comment: change private void gobut(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) to something like private void gobut_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

Comment: What did you changed?

Comment: this is what i changed `private void gobut_click`

Comment: Same error? Did you tried re-building the application? Hope this is the full code. Is there anything else?

Comment: yes. i did re-build. and i did all debugging methods as far i know.

Comment: Try closing the IDE and restart, try clean / build or rebuild solution.